# Multi browser testing with FluentAutomation and remote web drivers

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fluentautomation

I understand that according to the documentation, multi browser testing with local drivers is supported like this:

```
SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(
            SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Chrome,
            SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Firefox,
            SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.InternetExplorer
        );
```

And the tests are run in parallel on browsers. Is there a way do the same thing with remote web drivers? For a single browser, I do this:

```
SeleniumWebDriver.Bootstrap(new Uri("http://SampleURI"), SeleniumWebDriver.Browser.Firefox);
```

If not, what is a good way/ design to share test code among different browsers being tested? I will be using MSTest if it matters.